# Python pandas cell comma separated list keep only dublicates

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
import pandas as pd

# Source data
df = pd.DataFrame( data={'A': ['aaa, aaa, aaa', 'aaa, aaa, bbb', 'bbb, aaa, aaa', 'aaa, bbb, ccc'],'B': [ '1', '1', '1', '1']})

for row in df.iterrows():
    df['A'] = df['A']df['A'].duplicated()].unique()
```

Result:

> ValueError: Length of values (100) does not match length of index (1254)

I would like to show duplicated values:

```
df_2 = pd.DataFrame( data={'A': [ 'aaa', 'aaa', 'aaa', ''],'B': [ '1', '1', '1', '1']})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `collections.Counter` to count and filter the duplicates:

```
from collections import Counter
df["A"] = [ ",".join(k for k, v in Counter(ai.split(", ")).items() if v > 1) for ai in df["A"]]
print(df)
```

**Output**

```
     A  B
0  aaa  1
1  aaa  1
2  aaa  1
3       1
```